# why I can't show my converted video in web site?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, opencv, pythonanywhere

I made my web app using django and it works good in local server.
I uploaded slowmotion video and I could download my converted video on web
However, when I use AWS or pythonanywhere to release my website, I dosen's covert uploaded video. I can only show my uploaded origin video and there is nothing result. can you help me?

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
import cv2



def upload(request):
context = {}
if request.method == 'POST':
    uploaded_file = request.FILES['videoname']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    name = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
    context['url'] = fs.url(name)
    tujuan = context['url'][1:]
    modfile = tujuan + '.mp4'
    context['modurl'] = context['url']+'.mp4'
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(tujuan)
    # 재생할 파일의 넓이와 높이
    width = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
    height = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)
    print("재생할 파일 넓이, 높이 : %d, %d" % (width, height))
    # fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
    fourcc = 0x31637661
    out = cv2.VideoWriter(modfile, fourcc, 30.0, (int(height), int(width)))


    ret, pos_frame = cap.read()
    while (cap.isOpened()):
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        if ret == False:
            break;
        result = cv2.addWeighted(pos_frame, 0.5, frame, 0.5, 0)
        result = cv2.transpose(result)
        result = cv2.flip(result, 1)
        out.write(result)
        pos_frame = frame

    cap.release()
    out.release()

return render(request,'index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using [Django's default uploaded files handling](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/files/). Django stores files locally, using the `MEDIA_ROOT` and `MEDIA_URL` settings. [On PythonAnywhere](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles/) you have to set static files mapping from `MEDIA_URL` to `MEDIA_ROOT`. You set those constants in `settings.py` but you'll need to configure mappings in your "Web" configuration page at the "Static files" section on PythonAnywhere as well.